# How to group pixels in an image?

Tags: image-processing, cell, pixel

I want to group 16 pixels into a single unit in an image. 
For eg: If the image is a 16 x 16 image then the number of cells(ie, group of 16 pixels=1cell) that I would be creating will be 16. How to create a cell and display each cell with the respective pixel values?

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand the maths of your question, but let's assume you have this image which is 48x32 - I am showing the images 10x larger than life so you can see them.

[image]

I would use ImageMagick, which is installed on most Linux distros, and is readily downloadable for OS X and Windows. Download [here](http://imagemagick.org) or use `homebrew` on OS X.

I presume you want to chop the image up into lumps that measure 16x16, so you would use this command:

```
convert -crop 16x16 +repage tile%d.png
```

and you will get 6 output files, one red, one green, one blue, one black one white and one grey, called `tile0.png`, `tile1.png` ... `tile5.png`.

**tile0.png**

[image]

**tile1.png**

[image]